# Error in layout-normal-ldpi

Tags: android, layout, screen

I've decided to separate my layouts according to the dimensions of the screen and the density.
The files in
normal-ldpi do not work
small-ldpi either
the other files in the other folders are fine.

**Here is the error I have in my files :**

```
Exception raised during rendering: Index: 1, Size: 1
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log
```

**At ErrorLog I have :**

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.ninepatch.NinePatchChunk.draw(NinePatchChunk.java:174)
    at com.android.ninepatch.NinePatchChunk.draw(NinePatchChunk.java:101)
    at android.graphics.NinePatch_Delegate$1.draw(NinePatch_Delegate.java:219)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.GcSnapshot.drawInLayer(GcSnapshot.java:608)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.GcSnapshot.draw(GcSnapshot.java:577)
    at android.graphics.NinePatch_Delegate.draw(NinePatch_Delegate.java:217)
    at android.graphics.NinePatch_Delegate.nativeDraw(NinePatch_Delegate.java:170)
    at android.graphics.NinePatch.nativeDraw(NinePatch.java)
    at android.graphics.NinePatch.draw(NinePatch.java:104)
    at android.graphics.drawable.NinePatchDrawable.draw(NinePatchDrawable.java:188)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6725)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6743)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6743)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.render(RenderSessionImpl.java:466)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:320)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:325)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:440)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.renderWithBridge(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1545)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.recomputeLayout(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1302)
```

I use API Level 8, it should work shouldn't it?

**Here is the xml file corresponding to the error above**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:weightSum="10"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/fond">

    <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/imageView9"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_weight="2"
         android:scaleType="fitXY"
         android:src="@drawable/bandeau" />

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/layout2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="6"
        android:background="@drawable/fondshare"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:weightSum="2"
            android:layout_gravity="center" 
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView5"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/cadre" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView8"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/niceshot" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:weightSum="5"
            android:layout_gravity="center" 
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView7"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/enterthename" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_weight="1"             
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/sharefacebook" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_weight="1"             
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/sharetwitter" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView6"
                android:layout_weight="1"            
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/sharefacebook" />

        </LinearLayout>
     </LinearLayout>

     <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/imageView10"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_weight="2"
         android:scaleType="fitEnd"
         android:src="@drawable/dim" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the the same problem and I solved this problem by updating my SDK Manager i.e.previously i had SDK upto 4.0.3(API 15) installed in my eclipse...i installed Latest version 4.1.2 (API 16) and the error gone. Actually,it was a bug in previous libraries which solved in API 16 version.